# A child, a number and a food

Tags: riddle, knowledge

- *I am a child followed by a number followed by a food.*
- *High temperature precedes my nickname.*
- *I am symbolised by an animal standing on my toy.*

  ***Who am I?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am a child followed by a number followed by a food.

> TOT + TEN + HAM

High temperature precedes my nickname.

> Hotspurs

I am symbolised by an animal standing on my

> Tottenham's emblem is a cockerel standing upon a football
>
>    [image]

You are

> Tottenham Hotspur F.C.